# Dedicated thread pool for Kafka Streams tasks

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I don't see it in the docs, but still wanted to confirm if it's possible to assign a specific thread pool (`ExecutorService`) for a Kafka Streams tasks (using either of the DSL or `Processor` API) ? We can configure the number of threads so I was wondering if the above is possible

Comment: There is no API for this ATM. If you think it's a missing feature, please create a JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA

Comment: thanks for confirming - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5683